# Matlab: Extract Data from Structure and Transfer it into Cell Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure, tracking

I am quite new to Matlab and can't come up with a solution to the following problem:

From a single particle tracking program that uses Matlab (uTrack, to be precise) I get the tracking results as a structure. Inside this strucutre, the tracks of every particle is stored within another structure. In this structure, the tracks can then be found as a matrix (two other matrices are also there with other information) in the following way:

```
x coord / y coord / z coord / Amplitude / dx / dy / dz / dA ...
```

This would be for the first time point. Then it starts again with x coord, y coord, and so on for the second time point until the end.

For further evaluation, I only need the x and the y coordinates in a cell array in the following form

```
[t1 x1 y1;
 t2 x2 y2;
 t3 x3 y3;
 ...]
```

with one element in the cell array for each particle.

Therefore, I need to somehow extract the x and y coordinates, transfer them and add the time information in the first column with the correct lenght.

I have already tried to convert the data to a matrix, but the problem here is that the tracks have of course not all the same lengths. I get then a lot of NaN which cause problems in the following steps...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding the matrix containing x coord, y coord etc.? For instance what is its size?

Comment: It is 1x(8t) double, where t is the lentgh of the track - for example, a track with 20 time points results in a 1x160 double.

Comment: Your example is not a cell array, do you need it to be a cell array or are you happy with an array of doubles?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of code to help you fetch the data you want in the structure containing informations for each of the tracks.

In my sample code, I generate dummy values for the time, X- and Y coordinates and then put them in a cell array, which ultimately contains the data in the format you specified, for each time point.

I'm assuming that the information about the track is stored in the structure called DataStruct, with fields named X_Coord and Y_Coord. In your case, this information is in a matrix and thus the way in which indexing is performed in the structure will be different. As you said in the comments, the size of the matrix is 1x8(TimePoints), so you will have to play around with reshape for example to make it easier to access the elements in it.

```
clc;
clear all;

% Generate dummy values
for t = 1:10
DataStruct(t).X_Coord = t;
DataStruct(t).Y_Coord = 10*t+1;
end

Data_Cell = cell(length(DataStruct),3); % Pre-allocation

% Fetch each field of interest and put into cell array, along with the
% time.
for k = 1:length(DataStruct)

    Data_Cell(k,:) = {(k) (DataStruct(k).X_Coord) (DataStruct(k).Y_Coord)};

end

Data_Cell
```

This results in the following cell array:

```
Data_Cell = 

    [ 1]    [ 1]    [ 11]
    [ 2]    [ 2]    [ 21]
    [ 3]    [ 3]    [ 31]
    [ 4]    [ 4]    [ 41]
    [ 5]    [ 5]    [ 51]
    [ 6]    [ 6]    [ 61]
    [ 7]    [ 7]    [ 71]
    [ 8]    [ 8]    [ 81]
    [ 9]    [ 9]    [ 91]
    [10]    [10]    [101]
```

You can then convert to an array of doubles using `cell2mat`;
Hope that helps get you started!

**EDIT:**
Following your comment below, here is what you can do to identify the x and y coordinates that are both NaN ad store them in a new matrix along with their corresponding times:

```
DummyArray = zeros(10,3);

% Generate dummy array with numbers and NaNs.
DummyArray(:,1) = 1:10;
DummyArray(:,2) = [1 2 NaN NaN 5 6 7 8 NaN NaN];
DummyArray(:,3) = [NaN 21 NaN 41 51 NaN 71 81 91 NaN];
```

Which gives this dummy matrix:

```
DummyArray =

         1     1   NaN
         2     2    21
         3   NaN   NaN
         4   NaN    41
         5     5    51
         6     6   NaN
         7     7    71
         8     8    81
         9   NaN    91
        10   NaN   NaN

%Find row indices in which both x and y coordinates are actual numbers
NotNaN = DummyArray(~isnan(DummyArray(:,2)) & ~isnan(DummyArray(:,3)));

%Use logical indexing to retrieve the corresponding time, x- and y
%coordinates all in the same matrix.
FinalMatrix = [DummyArray(NotNaN,1) DummyArray(NotNaN,2) DummyArray(NotNaN,3)]
```

The output is the following:

```
FinalMatrix =

     2     2    21
     5     5    51
     7     7    71
     8     8    81
```

And there you go!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer! It helped, and I was able to get my data into a nicely seperated form. I have now the following: - One large, let's say 1000x1 double for the time - One double for x - And one for y (each column in it is for one particle). All I need is to fetch the time points and the x and y coords (t/x/y) and write them into a cell array, one element for each particle. Problem: There are a lot of NaNs in the x and y coords. It must be made sure that it (1) only takes the numbers and that (2) the time points are added accordingly (e.g. 46 x and y coords-->46 time points)

Comment: has anyone an idea how to do this? :)

Comment: Alright I'll will edit my answer shortly. In the meantime you can play around with ~isnan(Matrix) to find the elements in Matrix that are not NaNs. Oh and do you mean each row contains data for one particle?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understood how isnan works. In the doubles for the x and y coordinates, every column conatins the coords of one track so there are as many columns as there are tracks. From the top to the bottom the time increases - first row t0, second t1, third t2 and so on.

Comment: Alright @mtmtmt I made the changes please look at the edited answer :)